# GRUB customizer error during installation of ChromeOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I create a GRUB menu for ChromeOS which gives me errors when trying to update GRUB:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/99_brunch: 3: search: not found
/etc/grub.d/99_brunch: 4: loopback: not found
/etc/grub.d/99_brunch: 5: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

[image: screenshot of multiple overlapping windows of text]

Comment: ChromeOS is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). You can ask about ChromeOS on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), *but should you?* ChromeOS has quirks and difficulties booting on devices that aren't built for it. Why add extra complications to a low level system utility for a few seconds of eye candy? Many consider `grub-customizer` to be worse than useless, in that it doesn't really do anything of value, breaks too easily, and is either annoying and/or catastrophic when it breaks- depending on your skill level at solving such problems

Comment: @Nmath user is running Ubuntu in the screenshot, and tagged dual-boot. It appears they are trying to boot ChromeOS in addition to Ubuntu and running into trouble with grub, not sure if that changes whether it's off-topic

Comment: @Esther That's my exact issue here.

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1417856/edit) your question with more details. We will assume you are asking for help about another OS when you only ask about the other OS. Regardless, if the problem is that you're having trouble booting another OS, your question is really about that other OS even if you have Ubuntu installed. Make sure you've submitted your question to the SE that is most appropriate for your question. GRUB is topical, but ChromeOS boot is not.

Comment: So far I see nothing on-topic in the question; only non-Ubuntu OS & thus off-topic is mentioned; there is no mention of Ubuntu at all, nor any release details. Yes it looks like a Ubuntu theme & thus is possibly a Ubuntu system, however the question itself isn't yet on-topic due to nothing on-topic in it (no mention of Ubuntu and how the issue relates).  If the OS where `update-grub` is being run is an on-topic Ubuntu release (*we have no idea*) to me the question is on-topic, but we have no such information & only off-topic details provided & a picture that may/may-not be.  Please correct.